# How to use redux store of parent component

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am creating a component (- child) like `npm package` (- another project). This component will by use in another component (- parent) (will be installed like `npm i child`).

So, my problem is that I want to use redux store architecture in a child. In the parent, there is a too redux store architecture. In a child, I don't want to use own store **I want to use the store of the parent component**. How can I do this? How can I use the store of parent component in my child?

It is possible? I don't have any idea how to do it.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I can suggest you two options:

Comment: The point of using redux would be that all your state is in one store. Could you pull your store into a separate project and use it in all projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are more the one ways how to do it.

I prefer way with combine reducers.

In your child app create some reducer:

```
import {ACTIONS} from './actions';

const defaultState = {
    counter: 0,
};

export default function(state = defaultState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ACTIONS.PLUS:
            let newState = {...state};
            newState.counter++;
            return newState;
        case ACTIONS.MINUS:
            let newState2 = {...state};
            newState2.counter--;
            return newState2;
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

Export this reducer from project:
`export {default as YourReducer} from './your-reducer'`;

Now, in parent root reducer combine this reducer:

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux'

import app from 'app/containers/app/app-reducer'
import {YourReducer} from '@this-is-your-package/YourReducer'

export default combineReducers({
    app,
    YourReducer,
})
```

So, its all, now you can use `connect`, `mapStateToProps`, `dispatchToProps`, etc... in your child.

You can read parent state store too..

Parent store looks like this:

```
app: { ... }         // <-- parent
YourReducer: { ... } // <-- your child
```

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you two options:
1) Make a reducer of your child component and pass it to `combineReducer` in your reducer configuration. Then you will have access to global store.
2) Or you can simply pass whatever your child consumes from parent component as a props.

Comment: How can I pass store into my child, its not accessible while I using    <Provider store={store}>...